# Refresh screen react native bottomtab navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I have an app with a bottomtab with 4 tabs. I want that when I'm already on my "Home" screen, if I press the home bottomtab again in the menu, the screen will be refreshed, and it will eliminate that cache that it has. someone know how to I can do?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You can use the useFocusEffect hook provided by react navigation to do what you need.

Comment: What caching are you doing?